# Hide vimeo play bar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, vimeo

I'm trying to find out how to hide the play bar in bootstrap for a vimeo embed.

Here's the [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/T7caEUrPcE)

I tried doing it based off [this guy's code](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/cssplay-vimeo-hide-control-bar.html)

But I had no luck getting it to work within bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just use css to do this.

To hide the controls I just added a display none to the controls div

```
 div.controls {
     display: none;
 }
```

You can do specific controls just as just the progress bar or just the play button. It's all up to you.

Comment: Would you be able to supply me with a bootply - I can't figure out how a controls div links to vimeo

Comment: What do you mean by how a controls div links to vimeo, And how do I do a bootply?

Comment: No worries I ended up using youtube instead.